# How to control Flux streaming interval with a specified value from UI

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have defined reactive end point in the following way ( sample):

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Streams AMQ related monitor data.")
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent> streamCustomerData() {
        return monitorService.createFluxForInterval("customers",
                gridService::fetchAllCustomers);
    }

    public Flux<ServerSentEvent> createFluxForInterval(ProcessName processName,
                Supplier method) {
            return Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(intervalPeriod))
                    .map(serverSentEvent -> ServerSentEvent.builder(method.get()).event(processName.description()).build());
        }
```

I have configured intervalPeriod in the yml but I want to control it from the UI using a dropdown. Can anyone please suggest
And the angular code is in the following way

```
new Observable<any[]>(
  obs => {
    let eventSource = new EventSource("/customers");
    eventSource.addEventListener("customers", function (e: MessageEvent) {
      obs.next(JSON.parse(e.data));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have passed intervalPeriod as path param and also closed the existing connection (eventSource.close()) and opened a new one whenever there is a change in the intervalPeriod as a browser can have max of 6 connections.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared, it looks like your `intervalPeriod` is currently a property that is loaded from your application yaml when the Spring ApplicationContext is initialized.

Now since you need the interval period to be provided by the user/admin from UI, **it needs to be passed as a path param or query param of this API or some other API (if you want to re-use this interval period at other places, just store that info in-memory/cache/DB).**

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Streams AMQ related monitor data.")
    @GetMapping(path= "/customers", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent> streamCustomerData(@RequestParam("intervalPeriod") long intervalPeriod) {
        return monitorService.createFluxForInterval("customers",intervalPeriod,
                gridService::fetchAllCustomers);
    }

    public Flux<ServerSentEvent> createFluxForInterval(ProcessName processName, long intervalPeriod,
                Supplier method) {
            return Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(intervalPeriod))
                    .map(serverSentEvent -> ServerSentEvent.builder(method.get()).event(processName.description()).build());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. Path Param would work but how about angular code, what would happen to the earlier SSE connection? whenever the value with different interval is selected will that be a new connection?

Comment: so should I close and open new connection whenever an interval is selected from UI?